# Query using alias on column give an error

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

When i use alias for column i get error. Without alias everytinig works good. What is the problem with that ? This is simple example, but need to use more aliases in real project to wrap results in some not-entity class, but can't because of this error. How to solve this ?

**NOT WORKING** (with alias on id column):

```
public List<Long> findAll(Long ownerId) {
    String sql = "select id as myId  from products where ownerId = "+ownerId;
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    return query.list();
}
```

Error:

> WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter:77] : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022 ERROR
>   [JDBCExceptionReporter:78] : Column 'id' not found.

**WORKING** (without alias):

```
public List<Long> findAll(Long ownerId) {
    String sql = "select id from products where ownerId = "+ownerId;
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    return query.list();
}
```

Comment: Are you really concatenating a parameter? "SQL Injection"

Comment: @gbn - What could be injected besides a `Long` in this case? ;) - However, it's still a good point to always think about when doing plain SQL queries.

Comment: @Thomas: it shows OP doesn't know about SQL injection. If string values are handled safely it shows inconsistency. What of Long becomes String later?

Comment: not only injections, but also performance. As query plan with parameter can't be saved for future use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your "product" is mapped, hibernate probably don't know about "myId" and therefore can't select it.
You can try something like:

```
getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("myId", Hibernate.LONG)
```

Comment: Sometimes I forget about "addScalar", then google the error code and find this answer which I upvoted already in the past(