# PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for column_name on class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, named-query, hibernate3

I am facing the with hibernates named query and transform to bean.

Here is the code:

```
query = session.getNamedQuery( "LAST_ADDED_DOC" );
query.setString( "module", inNpUploads.getModuleName() );
query.setString( "mapping", inNpUploads.getMappingId() );
query.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( NpUploads.class ) );
dmsDb = query.list();
```

but the exception is thrown for `query.list()`:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for doc_id on class com.np.upload.pojo.NpUploads
    at org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.hql.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultList(CustomLoader.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    at com.np.upload.manager.FileUploadManager.listUploadedFiles(FileUploadManager.java:116)
    at com.np.upload.spring.controller.FileUploadController.prepareUploadPage(FileUploadController.java:222)
    at com.np.upload.spring.controller.FileUploadController.uploadPage(FileUploadController.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

The *hbm*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 30, 2015 10:32:57 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.np.upload.pojo.NpUploads" table="np_document_uploads" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="docId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="doc_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <version name="version" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="version" />
        </version>
        <property name="moduleName" type="string">
            <column name="module_name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingId" type="string">
            <column name="mapping_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="docType" type="string">
            <column name="doc_type" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="docName" type="string">
            <column name="doc_name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="docPath" type="string">
            <column name="doc_path" length="1024" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdTime" type="timestamp" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="created_time" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="modifiedTime" type="timestamp" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="modified_time" length="19" />
        </property>
    </class>
    <sql-query name="LAST_ADDED_DOC">
       <![CDATA[SELECT d.* FROM np_document_uploads d
                JOIN(
                    SELECT module_name, mapping_id, doc_type, max(version) AS version
                    FROM np_document_uploads u
                    WHERE u.module_name=:module and u.mapping_id=:mapping
                    GROUP BY module_name, mapping_id, doc_type
                )tt USING( module_name, mapping_id, doc_type, version )
                WHERE d.module_name=:module and d.mapping_id=:mapping]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the *pojo*:

```
public class NpUploads
    implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5063169354511880324L;
    private Integer           docId;
    private Integer           version;
    private String            moduleName;
    private String            mappingId;
    private String            docType;
    private String            docName;
    private String            docPath;
    private Date              createdTime;
    private Date              modifiedTime;

    // getter and setters for all properties are there.
}
```

Database schema:

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| doc_id        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| module_name   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| mapping_id    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| doc_type      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| doc_name      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| doc_path      | varchar(1024) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| version       | int(6)        | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_time  | timestamp     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| modified_time | timestamp     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `Transformers.aliasToBean` which uses the alias names to find the setter methods of your resultClass (`NpUploads`)

In order to make `Transformers.aliasToBean` work properly you need to use proper alias names in your query. If the property name in your `NpUploads` class is `docId`, you should use `select doc_id as docId`.

Remove `d.*` in you query and use individual column with proper aliases

Modify below and check [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/querysql-namedqueries.html) for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 30, 2015 10:32:57 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.np.upload.pojo.NpUploads" table="np_document_uploads" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="docId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="doc_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <version name="version" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="version" />
        </version>
        <property name="moduleName" type="string">
            <column name="module_name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingId" type="string">
            <column name="mapping_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="docType" type="string">
            <column name="doc_type" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="docName" type="string">
            <column name="doc_name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="docPath" type="string">
            <column name="doc_path" length="1024" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdTime" type="timestamp" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="created_time" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="modifiedTime" type="timestamp" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="modified_time" length="19" />
        </property>
        <loader query-ref="LAST_ADDED_DOC"/>
    </class>
    <sql-query name="LAST_ADDED_DOC">
        <return alias="up" class="NpUploads"/>       
        <![CDATA[SELECT d.doc_id as {up.docId},d.module_name as {up.moduleName},d.mapping_id as {up.mappingId},d.doc_type as {up.docType},d.doc_name as {up.docName},d.version as {up.version},d.doc_path as {up.docPath},d.created_time as {up.createdTime},d.modified_time as {up.modifiedTime} FROM np_document_uploads d
            JOIN(
                SELECT module_name, mapping_id, doc_type, max(version) AS version
                FROM np_document_uploads u
                WHERE u.module_name=:module and u.mapping_id=:mapping
                GROUP BY module_name, mapping_id, doc_type
            )tt USING( module_name, mapping_id, doc_type, version )
            WHERE d.module_name=:module and d.mapping_id=:mapping]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: I have changed the `d.*` to `d.doc_id as docId,d.module_name as moduleName,d.mapping_id as mappingId,d.doc_type as docType,d.doc_name as docName,d.version,d.doc_path as docPath,d.created_time as createdTime,d.modified_time as modifiedTime` and now the exception says: `IntegerType] - could not read column value from result set: doc_id; Column 'doc_id' not found.
JDBCExceptionReporter] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
JDBCExceptionReporter] - Column 'doc_id' not found`

Comment: check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118703/query-using-alias-on-column-give-an-error

Comment: he had used `hql` and I am using named query. how do it supposed to help?

Comment: what is the version of mysql connector ?

Comment: I am connecting it via `jdbc:datasource` in jboss

Comment: did you tried removing aliases as you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: check the version of mysql connector  in your build path ?

Comment: check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834777/hibernate-exception-propertynotfoundexception-when-using-transformer

Comment: I've just had this problem with some legacy code - when the query returns it capitalises the column names by default (using Oracle), so I had to put an explicit column alias in which preserved the case. In Oracle, this is done by using double quotes around the column alias in the query.

`String SQL = "SELECT d.doc_id AS \"DocId\""`

which then allowed the bean property to be derived properly.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is looking horrable but i was facing same issue. some time hibernate does not detect the properties setter and getter. i solved this problem by deleting all setter and getters from bean and then again create same by eclipse shorcut. it is working. 
you can do the same.

Comment: tried that but no luck... the issue seems to be with the named query.

Comment: run same query in database console

Answer (score 0):

> The types declared and used in the mapping files are neither Java
>   data types nor SQL database types. Instead, they are **Hibernate mapping
>   types**. Hibernate mapping types are converters which translate between
>   Java and SQL data types.

So java.lang.Integer is java type not hibernate mapping type,
see [Hibernate types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html)

Try changing `java.lang.Integer` to `integer`

```
<id name="docId" type="integer">
     <column name="doc_id" />
     <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

Comment: still the same exception.